# PostScript - Infinite paper size

Tags: linux, ghostscript, postscript

I've been making a program for a project of mine that creates a PostScript file whose output then I have to analyze.

The problem is indeed in the output, since the graphics consist of some hundred colored circles in succession, and with Ghostscript, for example, I can only visualize a small subset of them, even when I specify a paper size of *A0*.

In fact, even if could make the circles very tiny and tightened together, I want them to be readable and the overall sequence clear and analyzable (I can't draw more than one row): thus I'm asking you whether exist a way, or program, that "simulates" a paper with infinite paper size, perhaps with a scrolling bar.

If that wasn't quite possible using PostScript, would be there any other way by which I could make my program draw the entire sequence on screen?

**P.S.** By the way, I use Linux.

Comment: What stops you from outputting a scaled-down version to A0, then use a viewer (such as Ghostview), that can zoom in and scoll as much as you want?

Comment: @EugenRieck My knowledge about the matter, I suppose... I would be glad if you could put your solution as an answer

Comment: Assuming you need double-sized A0 ("A-2", 4x the area of A0): When creating the postscript, make everything half as big. Now view the resulting postscript file with ghostview and zoom in by a factor of 2. Result: Same view as A0, but with (more) scrolling possible for the double linear sizes.

Comment: Also, isn't there an option to use a "Bounding Box", i.e. specify the size of the "paper" freely?